# How to get last value from a KSQL stream when using window tumbling

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

How can I select the last record from a stream when using Window Tumbling?

I can not find any KSQL function for that.

I would like to achieve something like:

```
SELECT
  max(charge) AS maxCharge,
  last(charge) AS lastCharge
FROM charge_stream
WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 1 MINUTES)
GROUP BY deviceID
```

Except that last is not a valid KSQL function.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is [`LATEST_BY_OFFSET`](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-reference/aggregate-functions/#latest_by_offset).